# why the constructor and destructor of the same class object are implicitly called multiple times

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, destructor

English is not my native language，so please forgive me for my grammar problems.

When I run my program, I find that class constructors are called when defining objects and explicitly calling constructors。After calling the constructor and after leaving the scope, the destructor is called twice。

```
#include<iostream>
class test {
private:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
public:
    test(int first = 0, int second = 0, int third=0 );
    void show();
    ~test();
};

void test::show() {
    std::cout << this->a<<"\n";
}
test::test(int first , int second , int third ) {
    this->a = first;
    this->b = second;
    this->c = third;
    std::cout << "Construct\n";
}
test::~test() { std::cout << "destruct\n"; }

extern test myclassone;
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include "myhead.h"

test myclassone;
int main()
{
    std::cout << "begain\n";
    {
        std::cout << "mid\n";
        myclassone = test(1,1,1);
        std::cout << "mid\n";
        myclassone.show();
    }
    std::cout << "end\n";
}
```

The output of this program is

```
Construct
begain
mid
Construct
destruct
mid
1
end
destruct
```

In my expectation, constructors and destructors will only be called once. But what's puzzling is that according to the output, they were called twice.
I've googled this question, and many of the answers have not explained why the constructor is called when the object is defined, and why the destructor is called immediately after the constructor is called

Comment: One for your global `test myclassone`, another for your temporary `test(1,1,1)`.

Comment: It can be very enlightening to compile your code in debug mode and put a breakpoint on the constructor and destructor. The state of the call stack will tell you where you are and why a call to the con/destructor was created.

Comment: I don't see any reason for you to apologize for your English. I've seen native speakers do much worse.

Comment: The key is that there will be one destructor call for each constructor call. If you're seeing more destructor calls than you expect it almost always means that you're overlooking a constructor somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program runs as follows:

1. The constructor is called for the global object `test myclassone;`.
2. `main()` is called.
3. `begain` and `mid` are printed.
4. The constructor is called for the temporal object `test(1,1,1)`.
5. The temporal object is assigned to the global object.
6. The destructor is called for the temporal object `test(1,1,1)`.
7. `mid` is printed.
8. `myclassone.show()` is called.
9. `end` is printed.
10. Return from `main()`.
11. The destructor is called for the global object `test myclassone;`

Therefore the constructor and destuctor are called once for each objects and called twice in total.

Comment: Changing the constructor 'log' output would help see what's happening: `std::cout << "Construct\n" << a << " " << b << " " << c << std::endl;` will show that the *default* constructor is called once and the explicit one once.